# Providing input parameters from the Windows command line to a Matlab function compiled as a .exe

Tags: matlab, exe, command-prompt, input-parameters

Hi I have used `mcc` to convert a Matlab function into a standalone .exe. when I run the .exe file in the windows command prompt it returns the following error:

1. too many input arguments // when I give two inputs which is supposed to be
2. the first argument should have as many column as input variables as many rows as independent set of input values // when I give one input.

I used the command to build standalone : "mcc -mv myfile.m -a datfile.fis" ----------- building process is ok. But when I run with this command " myfile.exe 2.0 20.2 "in windows prompt it gives above errors. My program takes two inputs and gives one output. I have run Matlab tutorial magicsquare.m to convert magicsquare.exe on the same computer and works fine
Can anyone help please?
note before conversion the program runs fine in matlab I am given input as follows in MATLAB

> > myfile ([2.0 20.2])

Comment: If `myfile([2.0 20.2])` works correctly inside Matlab, then your function clearly only takes *one* input, since `[2.0 20.2]` is *one* variable (specifically a 2*1 vector). Further, I believe that any input from the Windows command line is interpreted by "compiled" Matlab as a string, so you'll need to use string inputs to your function then convert them using `str2num` at the top of your function.

Comment: Also, be careful with the windows command line splitting your argument at any whitespace character.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the executable from the Windows/DOS command line, the arguments get passed in to the executable as strings - as if you had within MATLAB called your function as `myfile "2.0" "20.2"`.

Each of these inputs is a character array (containing the ASCII values for "2", "." and "0" for example), so your function is likely erroring as there are too many inputs.

Try to rewrite your function so that it converts inputs to numbers using `str2num` or `str2double`. Alternatively store your inputs in a file, and design your function to accept the file name as input.

If you want it to behave differently when running in MATLAB and when running deployed, use the built-in function `isdeployed` in an `if` clause to switch behaviour.